# Is there an activity picker that displays the numbers on the images to show the order of selection with android jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-photo-picker

I am currently implementing a feature in Android where a user selects multiple media as part of the creation process of a Post. This media is then compressed and displayed in the order of selection by the user,

I was able to implement this in Android 12, but on testing with android 13, the media is arranged and returned in the order of images first, and the videos lost.

Does anyone have a work around to this, or is there a picker library that arranges media in order of selection and even displays the media with a number icon on top?

I am currently using the official Photo Picker library provided by google

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker

Here is an example on how I am handling the returned images as well as the compression.

```
val multiplePhotoPickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia(5),
        onResult = { data ->
            if (data.isNotEmpty()) {
                compressedVideos.clear()
                selectedImage.apply {
                    addAll(data)
                }
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    for (i in data.indices) {
                        val isImage = getMediaType(
                            context, data[i]
                        ) != MediaType.MediaTypeVideo
                        compressedVideos.add(
                            VideoItem(
                                data[i],
                                null,
                                false,
                                isImage,
                                "",
                               selectedMedias.size + i,
                                data[i].length(context)
                            )
                        )
                        Timber.tag("NoticeBoard").d("Item is Image ${isImage} is in postion ${i}")
                    }
                    val largeVideos = compressedVideos.filter { it.size > MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE }.map {
                        VideoItem(
                            it.currentPath,
                            it.currentPath,
                            it.isCompressed,
                            it.isImage,
                            it.itemId,
                            it.index,
                            it.size
                        )
                    }

                    compressedVideos.removeIf { it.size > MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE }
                    val compressor = MediaCompressor(context)
                    context.getActivity()?.let {
                        isCompressing.value = true
                        // function to compress videos
                        compressor.compressMultipleFiles(
                            it,
                            compressedVideos.filter { !it.isImage }.toMutableList(),
                            callback = { videosItems ->
                                //Compress Images
                                val images = compressImages(
                                    compressedVideos.filter { it.isImage }.toMutableList(),
                                    context
                                )
                                selectedMedias.addAll(images)
                                selectedMedias.addAll(videosItems)
                                selectedMedias.addAll(largeVideos)
                                selectedMedias.sortBy { it?.index }
                      
                                isCompressing.value = false
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: "I was able to implement this in Android 12" -- device manufacturers change system UI all the time. Please do not assume that you will get the media back in any particular order. If you need that, you will need to use `MediaStore` and build your own media picker UI.

Comment: Alright thanks. That's the option I have decided to go with.